# Handle "@" sign in proxy password

Tags: node.js, bash, curl, proxy, passwords

I'm making a curl request using a proxy. Let's say:

```
proxyUsername = "username"
proxyPassword = "p@ssw3rd"
proxyHost = "myproxy.node-a.io"
proxyPort = "11115"
```

You can construct a proxy request to ipinfo.io like so:

```
curl --proxy http://username:password@host:port https://ipinfo.io/ip
```

With the above proxy values the curl would look like:

```
curl --proxy http://username:p@ssw3rd@myproxy.node-a.io:11115 https://ipinfo.io/ip
```

The problem is that the first "@" sign in the password is seen as the token separator between password and host...

I've tried url encoding the password, but this doesn't work either:

```
curl --proxy http://username:p%40ssw3rd@myproxy.node-a.io:11115 https://ipinfo.io/ip
```

Is there any way to create a proxy authentication url like above for proxies that have "@" characters in their passwords?

(For context, I am trying to set the `--proxy-server` for a [chrome session](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack/socks-proxy).)

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/609888/481490):

> URLs use percent-encoding aka URL encoding.
>
> `@` sign is `%40` in this encoding.
>
> `% curl -k -X POST https://user1:mypass8%40@myshop.com/job/build`
>
> Or alternatively with `-u` / `--user` parameter:
>
> `% curl -u user1:mypass8@ -k -X POST https://myshop.com/job/build`